# Does anyone know what set this belongs to? Dark red, and greens

Tags: set-identification

Recently I bought a bunch of LEGO pieces and stuff from a garage sale, but one of the things I also got was this bag. The number says 135149 and it’s from 2011. I figure it might be from Star Wars due to the green laser pieces and maroon pieces, but I’m not sure. There might’ve been other bags that were supposed to go with it, small ones, but I can’t be sure.

[image]

Comment: Others better at this than I might be able to make out what the pieces are, but to me, it's quite blurry. If you could take another photo of *just* the pieces (no hand, no background) and make sure they're in focus, it might help us all.

Comment: What RSchulz said, or more detailed: open the bag, spread out the pieces on a white (or light monochrome) background to minimize overlap, then take a picture with the plane in focus where the pieces fill the frame but don't extend out of it and finally upload the photo in original (unreduced) size.

Answer (score 2):

While proper identification is only fully possible after you follow the comments of Zovits and RSchulz and include a better picture, I am pretty sure this bag belongs to set [75191 Jedi Starfighter with Hyperdrive](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75191-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). This is because:

- It has at least 3 bags due to its size (and you have a bag 3)
- It includes the [projectile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15303&idColor=108#T=S&C=108&O=%7B%22color%22:108,%22iconly%22:0%7D) in trans bright green
- It includes at least one of the [4x6 wedge plates](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32059&idColor=59#T=S&C=59&O=%7B%22color%22:59,%22iconly%22:0%7D) in dark red, visible in the right bottom of the bag. There are other sets with the projectile and dark red pieces (all in the Star Wars theme) but from what I can make out, 75191 is the only one with this wedge plate.

[image]